# how to get text of item checked in dhtmlx using`getAllChecked()`

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx to populate mysql data in treeview in php. Everything was fine, except, when I use `getAllChecked()` to get all the items checked as array, it shows identificators instead of text of the nodes. Is anyone of you have used [dhtmlx](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxtree:api_toc_alpha), can you please help me out in getting the text of node instead of id please?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment Dhtmlx doesn't provide a method to get the Tree Node Text of those Nodes that are checked.

But what it does have is the method to get all of the ID's of those checked and a way to get the nodes text by their id. In turn this is enough information to create your own method to get all of the text back for those checked.

You are more than welcome to use the method below if you don't want to write one yourself.

Here is what the method below does:

1. Get's all of the Checked Node ID's using dhtmlx's **tree.getAllChecked()**
2. Splits the returned string into an array.
3. Loops through the array of Checked Node ID's and uses dhtmlx's **tree.getItemText()** to get the text for each checked node.
4. While looping through it creates a string or array and returns it.

**Here is that function to get all the text of selected dhtmlx tree nodes.**

```
/**
 * Provide a list of Names from those Tree Nodes Checked
 * param: tree  (dhtmlx tree object)
 * optional: asArray (bool)  whether or not to return as an array 
 * return [] or ","
 */
var getAllCheckedItemsText = function(tree, asArray){

    var items = tree.getAllChecked();
    var listOfIDs = (items != "")?items.split(','):"";
    var listOfNames = [];
    for (i = 0; i < listOfIDs.length; i++){
        listOfNames.push(tree.getItemText(listOfIDs[i]));           
    }
    return (asArray != undefined && asArray == true)?listOfNames:listOfNames.join(',');

}
```

**How to use:**

Pass in the reference you have of your tree object in as a parameter and set the optional "asArray" flag. You will get the names back as an Array or just a string with commas separating the names, depending on the "asArray" flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 var text = tree.getItemText(id);
```